# Testing a function that takes an empty list

Tags: unit-testing, haskell, hunit

I'm trying to write a unit test for the simple function that takes a list and just returns it,

```
func :: [a] -> [a]
func x = x
```

using the test code to test that it works as expected when given an empty list

```
emptyListTest :: Test
emptyListTest = TestCase $ assertEqual "for (func [])," [] $ func []

main :: IO Counts
main = runTestTT $ TestList [emptyListTest]
```

However, I get the error

```
No instance for (Show a0) arising from a use of `assertEqual'
The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Note: there are several potential instances:
  instance Show Double -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance Show Float -- Defined in `GHC.Float'
  instance (Integral a, Show a) => Show (GHC.Real.Ratio a)
    -- Defined in `GHC.Real'
  ...plus 28 others
In the expression: assertEqual "for (func [])," []
In the second argument of `($)', namely
  `assertEqual "for (func [])," [] $ func []'
In the expression:
  TestCase $ assertEqual "for (func [])," [] $ func []
```

Other tests with non-empty lists work fine, and the function works fine when testing manually by calling `func []` in `ghci`.

I've also noticed that if I create a dummy type, and make a list taking elements of that type (if that's the correct way of saying it), then passing that to the test seems to work, and the test passes

```
data Dummy = Dummy
    deriving(Eq, Show)

emptyList :: [Dummy]
emptyList = []

emptyListTest :: Test
emptyListTest = TestCase $ assertEqual "for (func [])," [] $ func emptyList
```

Why is this? Is there a way to test functions with an empty list without going down the dummy type route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, the error tells you exactly what is wrong. Read it.

```
 The type variable `a0' is ambiguous
```

So, type your variable! GHC can't possibly know what type to use to test unless you do.

```
emptyListTest = TestCase $ assertEqual "for (func [])," [] $ func ([] :: [Int])
```

You may have to enable an extension to do it inline.

Comment: So why does the function work without error in the interpreter when I just pass it `[]` without a type?

Comment: @Michal Charemza GHCI has special inference rules.

Comment: To be more precise ghci defaults the `(Eq a, Show a)` constraint, arising from `assertEqual` constraint to `()`, this is an extension to Haskell's defaulting rules. See [here](https://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/users_guide/interactive-evaluation.html#extended-default-rules) for more details!

Comment: Simple type annotations on expressions don't require an extension. If you want the annotation on a pattern, or if it involves type variables shared with other parts of the code, you may need `ScopedTypeVariables`.

Comment: @yatima2975 or alternative, can you post the details of the contraints/extensions/inference rules in an answer?

Answer (score 1):

You need to provide a type for the empty list - otherwise GHC doesn't know what kind of list you are using.

One possible fix:

```
.... assertEqual "for (func [])," [] $ func ([] :: [Int])
```